# Add Javascript event to button in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, dom, onclick

In a database, a number of items are stored. When the user loads the page, the items are listed as rows of a table. To enable that the user can remove elements (rows), each row also provides a "Remove item" button with an `onclick` event attached to it. Here's the PHP part that generates the table.

```
for ($i=0; $i<$num_books; $i++)
{
    $book  = mysql_fetch_row($classics);
    $shop .= "<tr>\n";
    $shop .= "<td>".$book[0]."</td>\n";
    $shop .= "<td><input type='button' onclick='remove_item()' value='Remove' /></td>\n";
    $shop .= "</tr>\n";
}
```

The `remove_item()` function is defined externally in JQuery (see below).

However, now clicking the buttons results in an error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: remove_item`. I believe it's because the `remove_item()`functions which are returned by PHP are not known to the DOM.

How can this be corrected?

The *complete* markup is here

```
 <html>
     <head>
     <script type='text/javascript'
             src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript"
             src="../behaviour/interactions.js">
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>Publications database</h1>
         <div id="items"></div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

The *complete* `interactions.js` script is here

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    // Path to MySQL configuration.
    var server = '../server/'
    var data   = '../data/'

    function mysql_connection_setup()
    {
        $.get(data + 'mysql_connection_setup.php');
    }

    function populate()
    {
        $.get(server + 'shop.php', cb);
    }

    function remove_item()
    {
        console.log("Remove item.");
    }

    // Generic AJAX callback.
    function cb(response)
    {
        $('#items').html(response);
    }

    mysql_connection_setup();
    populate();
}); // End ready
```

Comment: Try `onclick='javascript: remove_item()'`. If the `remove_item()` function is defined in a page that is included on the current page, then this should work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it does not work. I get the same error message. Yes, `remove_item()` is defined in the Javascript that loads with the page.

Comment: To confirm this, if you right click on the page and choose `Inspect element` with Chrome, click on `Console` then type in `remove_item()` it should be triggered successfully. If it is not, then it's not properly included on the page.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. I entered `remove_item()` in the console and it's not recognized (`Can't find variable: remove_item`).

Comment: Then it is not being included or defined globally on the page. You're defining the function within the `$(document).ready()` function. You should place the function outside of this so it is globally accessible to the page.

Comment: I think the problem is that `remove_item` is added to the DOM on the server side, which the browser does probably not know about once the table comes back.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in the `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
  function remove_item()
  {
      console.log("Remove item.");
      // Fancy AJAX call to manipulate database.
  }
</script>
```

By doing this, it will be possible to access the function globally. Or, at least, you have to declare your functions `before` calling them.

Ok, here should be the solution:
First, declare variables globally.

```
<head>
  <script>
    var mysql_connection_setup, populate, remove_item, cb ;
  </script>
</head>
```

Then assign functions to the variables:

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    // Path to MySQL configuration.
    var server = '../server/'
    var data   = '../data/'

    mysql_connection_setup = function()
    {
        $.get(data + 'mysql_connection_setup.php');
    }

    populate = function()
    {
        $.get(server + 'shop.php', cb);
    }

    remove_item = function()
    {
        console.log("Remove item.");
    }

    // Generic AJAX callback.
    cb = function(response)
    {
        $('#items').html(response);
    }

    mysql_connection_setup();
    populate();
}); // End ready
```

You cannot declare function inside other functions. But you can create variables-callbacks inside.

Comment: The function `remove_item()` is defined in the Javascript which is loaded in the `<head>` of the page.

Comment: You could post some more code, so we could see how it is included.

Comment: @TMOTTM Check for the new answer.

Comment: I was not aware of that I can not declare functions inside other functions. To be explicit, also not in `ready()`?
However, the proposed solution works.

Comment: I'm reading ''Javascript & JQuery, The missing manual''. It's definitely not true that one can not define a new function within the `ready()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already including jQuery consider using its own functions for `click` and document ready.

I would change the PHP code to this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$num_books; $i++)
{
    $book  = mysql_fetch_row($classics);
    $shop .= "<tr>\n";
    $shop .= "<td>".$book[0]."</td>\n";
    $shop .= "<td><input type='button' class='myClass' value='Remove' /></td>\n";
    $shop .= "</tr>\n";
}
```

And at the `<head>` part of the HTML document i would add this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myClass').click(function(){
       console.log("Remove item."); //or call directly remove_item();
    });
});
```